# Data Splitting Proportions and Distributions

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, cross-validation

I am performing a machine learning task. I have data, 8163 observations in total, with which I will need to split into a train and test (holdout) set. I am also performing cross validation with the train set to prevent overfitting. My question is that does the distribution of the train, each validation fold and test set have to be roughly equal such as this:

[image: Distributions]

The first split between train and test is 93% (train). Then I used BlockedTimeSeriesSplit cross-validation, with 7 folds, each being split 50% for training and testing.

Comment: What does "0.5 for train and 0.5 for each validation fold" mean?  Why do you not have about 7592 in the training set and 571 in the test set, with about 1085 in each fold?

Comment: Each fold will be split in halve for training and testing. And these settings are the only way I can get the distributions to look roughly similar.

Comment: In the usual "training-(cross) validation-testing" paradigm as applied to time series, you separate out the most recent data as the test set and put it away until the very end. You then split the training set into folds, predict each fold based on the earlier training data and consider the quality of the results across all the folds.  You do this again and again with other hyperparameters, and eventually decide and fix the best hyperparmeters.  Using these, you train your model with the full training set and test that against your test set as a final measure of quality.

Comment: Thank you Henry this is useful! Should the distributions look similar?

Comment: If you are using time series, it is quite possible they will not (life now is not the same as the 2010s or the 2000s or the 1990s)